# I can't get windows authentication to work on IIS website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory

**Background**:

I am making a 'splash' page for my companies intranet (citrix access), on of the requirements is that the welcome message is personalised to the user viewing it, so it says 'Welcome Fred Jones'. This means I have to make an active directory request. I want to run the person's login (Domain\User.name) against active directory and return their name (Fred Jones)

**What I have tried**:

I have this code working locally but cannot seem to get it work on a live server:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
    "adurl.ad",
    "DC=company,DC=ad",
    "AccountUserName",
    "Password");
//UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
//UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "DOMAIN\\User.Name");
string displayName = user.DisplayName;
```

(Locally the 'DOMAIN\User.Name' is different to that on citrix so I hard coded in my username and this works locally)

I have set the web config to have windows authentication on, and I have also configured the server to only have windows authentication on. When I go to the website the windows security pop-up appears, I enter my details and it doesn't let me log in. Repeated tries leads to the following error message:

> HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

If I enable anonymous authentication then the page appears without a windows security prompt but then the 'User.Identity.Name' is blank.

I have looked through so many stack overflow questions and answers and can't quite find a fix for my issue, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you create your application as an intranet application? http://imgur.com/a/nIdaI

Comment: I tried that and got the same issues, but that led me to the fact it was an environment issue which I have now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, adding `IIS_IUSRS` to the website folder permissions allowed and gave full access allowed my website to work correctly.